# Проверка на символы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как прoверить, есть ли в input type="text" определенные символы с помощью js, например, мне надо проверить, присутствует ли символ @ в значении, которое пользователь ввел в форму

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: И ещё, как проверить, сколько символов ввел пользователь в форму

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp

Answer (score 5):

1. [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
console.log(input.value.includes('@'));
```

```html
<input id='input' value='123@123' />
```

2. [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
console.log(input.value.indexOf('@') !== -1);
```

```html
<input id='input' value='123@123' />
```

3. Регулярные выражения

```js
console.log(/@/.test(input.value));
console.log(!!input.value.match(/@/));
console.log(input.value.search(/@/) != -1);
```

```html
<input id='input' value='123@123' />
```

4. Пройтись циклом по символам

```js
for(let char of input.value) if(char == '@') console.log(true);
```

```html
<input id='input' value='123@123' />
```

5. Более извращенные способы

```js
console.log(input.value.split('@').length != 1);

console.log(input.value.replace('@', '') != input.value);

console.log(!![...input.value].find(el => el == '@'));

console.log([...input.value].findIndex(el => el == '@') != -1);

console.log([...input.value].lastIndexOf('@') != -1);

console.log([...input.value].filter(el => el == '@').length != 0);

console.log([...input.value].some(el => el == '@'));

console.log(![...input.value].every(el => el != '@'));

console.log([...input.value].reduce((has, el) => has || el == '@', false));
```

```html
<input id='input' value='123@123' />
```

To be continued...